# Relative paths not working if batch file calls exe based on OS architecture

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, batch-file

I have a requirement where I need to run a particular .exe based on the architecture.

My folder structure is like this:
[image: Main folder hierarchy]

The Tools folder looks like this
[image: Tools folder]

Under that the Binaries folder contains 2 sub folder (one each for 32/64 bit)
[image: Binaries]

Each of these folders (x64/x32) looks like below:
[image: X64 folder (same is x32 folder also)]

The Root folder contains the .bat (start.bat) file that calls the appropriate exe (For example:  if it is 32bit, it calls "\Binaries\x86\Tool.exe" or if it is 64bit, it calls "\Binaries\x64\Tool.exe".

The code in start.bat is as below:

```
@ECHO OFF
if exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\" (
   start "" /d "%~dp0" "Binaries\x86\Tool.exe"
) else (
   start "" /d "%~dp0" "Binaries\x64\Tool.exe"
)
```

The calling is fine and it calls the particular .exe. The problem comes when the .exe application tries to use the XML file (each folder also contains a XML file, parameters.xml, along with exe) it throws an error. I am accessing the XML file using relative paths like ("./parameters.xml").

I tried recoding the code by using "System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" (as this is a WPF exe). That works for relative path, but another scenario fails. I will explain the same below:

In the application i am getting the instances of SQL installed on the machine. To achieve that I am using the following code:

```
internal static List < string > SQLServerInstances() {
    var sqlInstances = new List < string > ();

    try {
        using(RegistryKey sqlKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "").
        OpenSubKey(@
        "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL")) {
            if (sqlKey != null) {
                foreach(string versionKeyName in sqlKey.GetValueNames()) {
                    sqlInstances.Add(versionKeyName);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception de) {
        throw de;
    }
}
```

This code returns no instances if I use the batch file to run the .exe. If I run the .exe directly from "Binaries\x64\Tool.exe", this code passes and returns me the SQL instances properly.

I am not sure what the issue is. This might be expected behaviour but seems a bit weird.

Comment: You have a problem with registry (not relative paths). Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Don't put your resource files in your bin folder... if you put them in a folder higher up the hierarchy, it would be accessed with the same path regardless of which solution configuration was running.

Comment: @DrKoch :  I did not get that. If there is a problem with registry how come the same code runs when i run from exe directly and not from the batch.

Comment: @Sheridan: I know that, but my requirement is such that it is the best place for the file. I am not sure if i move the file one folder up i will still be accessing it as "././Parameters.xml". I think i will hit the same issue because the root folder it is taking is from BatchFile and not the EXE folder.

Comment: Have you tried using `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)` to get the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your start.bat code this way:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd "%~dp0"
if exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\" (
   start "" "Binaries\x86\Tool.exe"
) else (
   start "" "Binaries\x64\Tool.exe"
)
```

Comment: This works as far paths are concerned. I need to check on the registry issue though :)